# How to host WCF in IIS as a sub-application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, iis

I have a webserver with the Default application and a Sandbox application.  I now want to publish WCF services as a sub application for each.
e.g.

- ://www.mydomain.com/services
- ://sandbox.mydomain.com/services

From Visual Studio, I have configured a publish profile for Sandbox as Such

- server: ://myipaddress:8172/msdeploy.axd
- sitename: Sandbox/Services destination
- url:://sandbox.mydomain.com/services

Once published, the application is available under sandbox as I expect. However, I am receiving a generic error from my browser:

*Runtime Error
Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated. 
Looking through the Application Event Log, I see that I have a configuration error and that the application is not able to load an assembly.  In this case it is DevExpress Libraries.  These libraries are not referenced by the WCF services; however they are referenced by the Sandbox application.
Event Log Entry
Event code: 3008 
Event message: A configuration error has occurred. 
Event time: 2/1/2018 1:06:06 PM 
Event time (UTC): 2/1/2018 6:06:06 PM 
Event ID: 54ba6fe939ec46deb0526c36e13579d3 
Event sequence: 1 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/Services-7-131619819656314908 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: /Services 
    Application Path: \Sandbox\Services\ 
    Machine name:  
Exception information: 
    Exception type: ConfigurationErrorsException 
    Exception message: Could not load file or assembly 'DevExpress.Web.v16.2, Version=16.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

I've added references to the first couple of Devexpress Libraries, as they appeared.  And the exception just points to yet another library in the root application.  This is not sustainable, the two should be independent.

I created a new application pool, thinking that this was some sort of inheritance issue.  That did not work.

How do I prevent the WCF services from wanting to load these libraries.  And still allow these services to be published a sub applications?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please do not SHOUT when posting your questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the root cause of and solution for my issue.  The cause is by design in IIS.  Web.Config files are inherited by child applications from their root applications.  To prevent this there are two mechanisms available to you:

- Leverage the `<location>` tag and set the inheritInChildApplications
  property to false for sections you do not want inherited.  You place
  these tags in your root application's web.config.
- Leverage the `<remove />` and `<clear />` in your child application's
  web.config where you want to start with a clean slate.

In my scenario, I placed the `<location>` tag around system.web of the root web.config and used the `<clear>` tag in my child web.config for connectionStrings and appSettings

Comment: Hello, I've encountered this problem. Could you show me how and where to place the `<location>` tag please?